# Custom OrderBy on a List based on a string property value

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, linq

I have the following class :

```
public class Document
{
    public string DocumentSection { get; set; }
    public string DocumentName { get; set; }
}
```

and I would like to order the following list based on the DocumentSection property:

```
List<Document> documents = new List<Document>();
        documents.Add(new Document { DocumentSection = "Section One", DocumentName = "doc1" });
        documents.Add(new Document { DocumentSection = "Section Two", DocumentName = "doc1123" });
        documents.Add(new Document { DocumentSection = "Section Three", DocumentName = "doc113" });
        documents.Add(new Document { DocumentSection = "Section Four", DocumentName = "doc123" });
        documents.Add(new Document { DocumentSection = "Section Five", DocumentName = "doc11" });
```

In theory I know that I should implement IComparer to obtain that, but this is where the difficulty comes in, I am not very sure how can I achieve that on a general level ... what is the best solution to achieve this ordering ?

Comment: Is `DocumentSection` always comes with Section One, Section two,... e.t.c, then one of way is that to change one, two...(trimming Section string) to numeric and to the order. Another Solution is that instead of having Document Section as String, have it as numeric value and do the sorting over that. If the property is required to display the text on bind view, then write a converter to change the numeric value to Text (with required pre and post fix strings.)

Comment: yes it's always like that .. the thing is that I am not able to change the model structure at all

Comment: "Section One", "Section Two", "Section Three" ... and so on ... "Section One Hundred" ... it's bad ... but I have to deal with this real case scenario now ... a big switch statement will do the job ... or a Dictionary<string,int>  {"One", 1"} {"Two", 2 "} etc ... but I have to write by hand all this cases ... and I was curios if there are better alternatives

Comment: If the section was 1001 what would the **specific** value of `DocumentSection` be? What about if it was 10914?

Comment: @RaduOlteanu Check my Code, that's **support all number** `....,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,....` and don't need to write any number to word .... check that, I'm sure that's good for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var orderedList = documents.OrderBy(r => GetOrder(r.DocumentSection));
```

and the `GetOrder()` method is:

```
Public Static int GetOrder(string _arg)
{
    switch (_arg)
    {
        case 'Section One':
            return 1;
        case 'Section Two':
            return 2;
        case 'Section Three':
            return 3;
            .
            .
            .
        default:
            return int.MaxValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: @RaduOlteanu I think this most obvious solution is the clearest one

Comment: This wouldn't even compile. Capitalization is wrong, the paramater doesn't match the switch argument.

Comment: The argument of switch typed wrongly, however it was obvious but i edited it

Answer (score 0):

easiest way is to use Linq :

```
List<Order> SortedList = objListOrder.OrderBy(o=>o.Order).ToList();
```

Sample :

```
List<Document> SortedList = documents.OrderBy(o=>o.DocumentName).ToList();
```

---

**Long Answer**
you need to customize above order method but you don't need to type all number in this code

with `wordify` method you can convert ***number to word*** and

with `normalize_number` method we normalize both `result word` and `first word` so we can check result word with first word

we have a loop and we don't like to create word always so we can use from `Dictionary` and check number, we do this in `get_wordify` method.

now with `SetOrder` we can find correct order

So Just Use from this code :

```
    private int current_order = 0;
    private int SetOrder(string _arg)
    {

        string number = _arg.ToLower()
            .Replace("section", "")
            .TrimStart(' ')
            .TrimEnd(' ');
        number = normalize_number(number);

        for (int i = 0;
            //you can limit loop here (i<99999) or not !
            ; i++)
        {
            string wordify_number = get_wordify(i);

            if (wordify_number == number)
            {
                //if all number is available return i+1
                //return i + 1;

                //otherwise
                current_order++;
                return current_order;
            }

        }

    }
    private string normalize_number(string number)
    {
        number = number.Replace("-", " ")
                        .Replace("_", " ")
                        .Replace(",", " ");

        //also you can replace "and" if you want 

        //.Replace("  ", " "); 
        //regex is better for find and replace multi space

        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.None;
        Regex regex = new Regex("[ ]{2,}", options);
        number = regex.Replace(number, " ");


        return number;
    }

    Dictionary<int, string> Numbers_dic = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    private string get_wordify(int i)
    {
        string wordify_number = "";
        if (Numbers_dic.ContainsKey(i))
        {
            wordify_number = Numbers_dic[i];
        }
        else {
            wordify_number = wordify(i);
            wordify_number = normalize_number(wordify_number);

            Numbers_dic.Add(i, wordify_number);
        }

        return wordify_number;
    }
    private string wordify(decimal number)
    {
        if (number == 0) return "zero";
        var units = " one two three four five six seven eight nine".Split();
        var teens = " eleven twelve thir# four# fif# six# seven# eigh# nine#".Replace("#", "teen").Split();
        var tens = " ten twenty thirty forty fifty sixty seventy eighty ninety".Split();
        var thou = " thousand m# b# tr# quadr# quint# sext# sept# oct#".Replace("#", "illion").Split();
        var minus_str = (number < 0) ? "minus " : "";
        var res_number = "";
        var p = 0;
        number = Math.Abs(number);
        while (number > 0)
        {
            int b = (int)(number % 1000);
            if (b > 0)
            {
                var h = (b / 100);
                var t = (b - h * 100) / 10;
                var u = (b - h * 100 - t * 10);

                var str = ((h > 0) ? units[h] + " hundred" + ((t > 0 | u > 0) ? " and " : "") : "")
                      + ((t > 0) ? (t == 1 && u > 0) ? teens[u] : tens[t] + ((u > 0) ? "-" : "") : "")
                      + ((t != 1) ? units[u] : "");
                str = (((number > 1000) && (h == 0) && (p == 0)) ? " and " : (number > 1000) ? ", " : "") + str;

                res_number = str + " " + thou[p] + res_number;
            }

            number = number / 1000;

            if (number < 1)
            {
                break;
            }

            p++;
        }
        return minus_str + res_number;
    }
```

Usage :

```
private void Do_order()
{
    var orderedList = documents.OrderBy(r => SetOrder(r.DocumentSection));
}
```

Comment: The OP ls looking to sort by `DocumentSection`. This code will order the items alphabetically ("five" and "four" will be before "one").

Comment: yes, edited, now it's better then first accepted answer !