# C# Sorting Listview

Tags: c#, listview

This might be easy. I have few question. My listview items have a data like this

```
col/row Name age distance

        Flick 20 1.4
        Hamn  19 0.9
        John  19 1.0
```

And I want to sort the list view by checking the lowest distance. So Its gonna be like this:

```
col/row Name age distance

        Hamn  19 0.9
        John  19 1.0
        Flick 20 1.4
```

I am trying to use a listview control name `Sorting`. But it not working.
My question is how I am gonna sort the data by checking item.subitems[2] and make my listview to be like the new one above.PS.Also my data have more than 3 data not just `Hamn,John,Flick`.

Thanks you very much.

Comment: check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50550448/custom-orderby-on-a-list-based-on-a-string-property-value/50550557#50550557

Comment: Been a long time since I have done it, but I think you can implement a custom comparer that will be called be the ListView when it is sorted,  The comparer would compare the distance of your items.  See the ListViewItemSorter property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very simple example using the ListViewItemSorter property.  It assumes that distance is ALWAYS the third column (second subitem):

```
private class ItemComparer : IComparer
{
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        // Convert objects to ListViewItems
        ListViewItem i1 = x as ListViewItem;
        ListViewItem i2 = y as ListViewItem;

        // If converstion to ListViewItems failed, return -1 (less than)
        if (i1 == null) return -1;
        if (i2 == null) return -1;

        // If ListViewItems DO NOT have the correct number of subitems, return -1 (less than)
        if (i1.SubItems.Count < 2) return -1;
        if (i2.SubItems.Count < 2) return -1;

        // Convert subitem 2 (index 1) text to a numeric value
        double distance1, distance2;
        if (!Double.TryParse(i1.SubItems[1].Text, out distance1)) return -1;
        if (!Double.TryParse(i2.SubItems[1].Text, out distance2)) return -1;

        // Compare the distance1 to distance2 (-1 = less than, 0 = equal, 1 = greater than)
        return distance1.CompareTo(distance2);
    }
}


public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { "Flick", "20", "1.4" }));
    listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { "John",  "19", "1.0" }));
    listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { "Hamn", "19", "0.9" }));

    listView1.ListViewItemSorter = new ItemComparer();
    listView1.Sort();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I have some question. Where is the point that will check item.subitem[2] (distance).

Comment: I added comments to better explain the custom comparer.  When you call sort() on the list view, it will call the comparer with "pairs" of the ListViewItem that you have added to determine their sort order.

Comment: I can't create a new class. Its say error at IComparer.

Comment: What's the error?  You will need a "using System.Collections" statement to "include" the IComparer interface.

Comment: If I want it to check the item.subitems[7]. So i have to change (i1.SubItems.Count < 2) to (i1.SubItems.Count < 7) and i1.SubItems[1].Text to i1.SubItems[6].Text? Is that correct?

Comment: Thanks it work now!!. Sorry that my reputation is not meet the requirement to approve the answer.

Comment: Yes, I'm just doing some simple "range" checking there to make sure the data exists before I try to access it.  The index is zero based so it is 1 less than the count.

Comment: @Marker Really ? Why ? just need one line of code ..`var list = List_unsort.OrderBy(x => x.number);`

Comment: @MrUnknow, I guess if you don't add items (to the list view) or want to change the sorting by clicking on a column header.  I don't think the list view has a datasource so you would have to repopulate it every time the list and/or order changed.

Answer (score 1):

```
var orderedList = your_list.OrderBy(r => r.subitem);
```

And also you can use from your own sorting method (I think don't required in your case)

usage :

```
var orderedList = your_list.OrderBy(r => GetOrder(r.subitem));
```

sample method :

```
Public Static int GetOrder(string _arg)
{
    switch (_arg)
    {
        case 'Section One':
            return 1;
        case 'Section Two':
            return 2;
        case 'Section Three':
            return 3;
            .
            .
            .
        default:
            return int.MaxValue;
    }
}
```

**-------------Edit : Added Example Project --------------------**

Just Use from this code :

```
var list = List_unsort.OrderBy(x => x.number);
```

**Example Project :**

```
public static void Main()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Start Work ...\r\n");

        Create_list();

        Sort_list();

        Console.WriteLine("\r\nFinish.");

    }

    private static List<custom_item> List_unsort = new List<custom_item>();

    private class custom_item
    {
        public int id { get; set; }

        public string name { get; set; }

        public double number { get; set; }
    }


    private static void Create_list()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        Console.WriteLine("Unsort List : ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            custom_item item = new custom_item();
            item.name = i.ToString();
            item.id = i;

            double rnd_num = rnd.NextDouble();
            item.number = rnd_num;

            Console.WriteLine("ID : " + item.id + ", number : " + item.number);
            List_unsort.Add(item);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\r\n--------------------\r\n");
    }

    private static void Sort_list()
    {
        var list = List_unsort.OrderBy(x => x.number);
        Console.WriteLine("Sort List : ");
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ID : " + item.id + ", number : " + item.number);
        }
    }
```

and Output :

> Start Work ...
>
> Unsort List :  ID : 0, number : 0.333175984366413
>
> ID : 1, number : 0.886352685227223
>
> ID : 2, number : 0.633657003582295
>
> ID : 3, number : 0.319651832021611
>
> ID : 4, number : 0.340439343983512
>
> ID : 5, number : 0.476074807567557
>
> ID : 6, number : 0.664470672451179
>
> ID : 7, number : 0.14823883685667
>
> ID : 8, number : 0.375242880254631
>
> ID : 9, number : 0.186346486763259
>
> ---
>
> Sort List :
>
> ID : 7, number : 0.14823883685667
>
> ID : 9, number : 0.186346486763259
>
> ID : 3, number : 0.319651832021611
>
> ID : 0, number : 0.333175984366413
>
> ID : 4, number : 0.340439343983512
>
> ID : 8, number : 0.375242880254631
>
> ID : 5, number : 0.476074807567557
>
> ID : 2, number : 0.633657003582295
>
> ID : 6, number : 0.664470672451179
>
> ID : 1, number : 0.886352685227223
>
> Finish.

Link for Compile and test project :

http://rextester.com/NHFTU85530

OR

https://dotnetfiddle.net/GWWNgb

Comment: Sorry, I am a beginner. What is case 'Section One' ? What I have to change it to?

Comment: @Eddga : What are you doing ! I said in your case you don't need for custom method for sorting ! just need to use like this : `var list = List_unsort.OrderBy(x => x.subitem);`  here is a working example : [link1](http://rextester.com/NHFTU85530) OR [link2](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GWWNgb)

Comment: Thank you. This answer also working too. But I am sorry that it can approve only 1 answer. :(